# How to add squares to the back of my R plot?

Tags: r, plot

I have a plot in R using the 'plot()' function.

[image: My current plot]

I would like to add a square backing to the plot (so that it looks like it is drawn on square paper), to help with readability. How can I do this? An example of what I mean would be the light gray lines seen is this desmos plot:

[image: What I would like to see]

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Call [grid](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/grid.html) function after plot, e.g. `grid(nx=NULL,ny=NULL,col="lightgray",lty="dotted",lwd=par("lwd"),equilogs=TRUE)`

Comment: @digEmAll thanks! Worked a treat. Add it as an answer if you want. :)